# Cannot run VMware on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, vmware-player, liveusb

I am running kali linux using persistence USB and I was trying to install VMware. After installation when I open VMware I get this error: "***C header files matching your running kernel were not found.  Refer to your distribution's documentation for installation instructions.***". So I tried this command: `apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)` and I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64'
```

The command `uname -a` gives me this:

```
uname -a
Linux kali 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.18-1kali1 (2017-04-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And `uname -r` gives me this: `4.9.0-kali3-amd64`

I have updated kali linux but it does not seem to solve this problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands **First**:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms
```

And then run (to install kernal headers)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: After running this command: `sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms` i get this: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.3).
build-essential set to manually installed.
dkms is already the newest version (2.3-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 60 not upgraded.`
And then the same error as before to install the kernel headers

Comment: I did this command as well: `sudo apt-get upgrade` but still same error after i run this: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` I get this: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64'`

Comment: try these commands `apt-cache search linux-headers` & then `apt-get install linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-amd64`

Comment: This is what I get `linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-amd64 is already the newest version (4.9.30-1kali1).` but then again when I run `uname -r` I get `4.9.0-kali3-amd64`. I read in some places that because it is running on live USB the kernel is unable to change and it will always boot on the kernel of the ISO that was installed in the USB but then I found this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364457/how-to-change-the-boot-kernel-of-a-usb-live-w-persistent-running-kali where this guy claims to have found a solution but I cannot understand the paths.